# Upgraded from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS, Spamassassin Upgrade Issue

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 14.04, permissions

I recently upgraded my server from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.

Mostly everything went well.  However one thing isn't working for me and I'm trying to figure out what I missed.

I re-visited the settings and confirmed they were set to what I had before the upgrade, but now when SpamAssassin tries to update at night my cron job emails me this:

```
/etc/cron.daily/spamassassin:
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir `/var/lib/spamassassin/sa-update-keys'
gpg: failed to create temporary file `/var/lib/spamassassin/sa-update-keys/.#lk0x16728d0.mail.nomorestars.com.13916': Permission denied
gpg: keyblock resource `/var/lib/spamassassin/sa-update-keys/secring.gpg': general error
gpg: failed to create temporary file `/var/lib/spamassassin/sa-update-keys/.#lk0x16728d0.mail.nomorestars.com.13916': Permission denied
gpg: keyblock resource `/var/lib/spamassassin/sa-update-keys/pubring.gpg': general error
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `/usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update-pubkey.txt': general error
gpg: import from `/usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update-pubkey.txt' failed: general error
gpg: process '/usr/bin/gpg --homedir='/var/lib/spamassassin/sa-update-keys' --batch --no-tty --status-fd=1 -q --logger-fd=1 --import' finished: exit 2
```

I've checked and the user account settings and permissions appear correct. Any suggestions on where I can look?   I'm sure it's something that was changed permission by the upgrade I just can't seem to locate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this link: http://krischan.eu/index.php/2014/04/21/spamassassin-bug-gpg-validation-failed/

Looks like they had a similar problem and ended up re-importing the GPG key.

Mike